# SQL Query - Single SELECT instead of UNION

Tags: postgresql, union

Building a social site which allows users to follow each other, and enforcing a business rule that only allows DMs when two users mutually follow each other.

Follows are stored in a lookup:

```sql
TABLE FOLLOWS
- userA_ID FK
- userB_ID FK
```

Given this dataset in the `FOLLOWS` table:

```sql
|userA_ID  |userB_ID  |
-----------------------
|123       |456       | <- Gerald follows Jane
|789       |456       | <- Grace follows Jane
|456       |789       | <- Jane follows Grace
```

If I'm logged in as Jane, I can DM Grace but not Gerald, and vice-versa.

My current Query....

```sql
--  mutual followers
SELECT DISTINCT (u.id) AS userId, u."name" AS "userName"
FROM "Follows" 
    INNER JOIN "User" u ON u.id = "userA_ID"
WHERE "userB_ID" = $1
INTERSECT
SELECT DISTINCT (u.id) AS "userId", u."name" AS "userName"
FROM "Follows" 
    INNER JOIN "User" u ON u.id = "userB_ID"
WHERE "userA_ID" = $1
```

...feels clunky. Is there a way to write this in a single SELECT instead of with a UNION?

Comment: A UNION does not function *as a single query*. It's actually three separate operations - two separate SELECTs and then a merging operation that removes duplicates (unless you specify UNION ALL).

Comment: You probably _shouldn't_ try to rewrite as one query, as your current version can be optimized by introducing an index.

Comment: I don't think this actually queries "mutual followers" as your comment indicates. Rather, it returns all the users that either follow $1 **or** are followed by $1. Maybe you meant to use `INTERSECT` instead of `UNION`?

Comment: Bergi thanks and updated. 
Tim Biegeleisen I am using indexes. 
Ken White thanks for the clarification, updated.

Comment: Oh wow now that makes it a completely different thing :-)

Comment: `distinct` is **not** a function. It always applies to all columns in the select list. Enclosing one of the columns with parentheses won't change anything and is useless. `distinct (a),b` is the same as `distinct a,(b)` or `distinct a,b`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you don't need to use <s>`UNION`</s> `INTERSECT`. The intersection is basically computed as a `WHERE EXISTS(…)` statement checking for the same values to be in the result of the second query. But the query to arrive at these results can be simplified a bit by using `EXISTS` directly - you don't need to join `User` again:

```
SELECT DISTINCT (u.id) AS "userId", u."name" AS "userName"
FROM "Follows" x
INNER JOIN "User" u ON u.id = x."userA_ID"
WHERE x."userB_ID" = $1
  AND EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM "Follows" y
    WHERE y."userA_ID" = $1 -- x."userB_ID", for more symmetry
      AND y."userB_ID" = x."userA_ID"
  )
```

Btw you can also drop the `DISTINCT (u.id)` - if your primary keys / unique constraints on `User(id)` and `Follows(userA_ID, userB_ID)` are set up correctly then this query can't generate multiple rows for the same user.

And you can actually express that `WHERE EXISTS(*)` as another `JOIN`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT (u.id) AS "userId", u."name" AS "userName"
FROM "Follows" x
INNER JOIN "Follows" y ON (y."userA_ID" = x."userB_ID" AND y."userB_ID" = x."userA_ID")
INNER JOIN "User" u ON u.id = x."userA_ID"
WHERE x."userB_ID" = $1
```

Another approach to simplify the query is to move the intersection to a straightforward subquery specifically for mutual followers:

```
SELECT u.id AS "userId", u.name AS "userName"
FROM "User" u
JOIN (
  SELECT "userA_ID", "userB_ID" FROM "Follows"
  INTERSECT
  SELECT "userB_ID", "userA_ID" FROM "Follows"
) AS mutual(a, b) ON mutual.a = u.id
WHERE mutual.b = $1
```

Comment: The middle approach is exactly what I was looking for. Appreciate the extra explanation and exploration. Thanks!

Interested in extra credit question? :)

Comment: You can always [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)

Answer (score 0):

What you need is an `inner join`
and what people mostly don't know is that you're not limited to a simple `a.id = b.a_id`

### Answer

```
select left_side.userA_ID as user_one, left_side.userB_ID as user_two
from follows as left_side 
    inner join follows as right_side on 
        left_side.userA_ID = right_side.userB_ID and 
        left_side.userB_ID = right_side.userA_ID
```

and get

```
 user_one | user_two
----------+----------
      456 |      789
      789 |      456
(2 rows)
```

As for how to make only one row, I don't yet know
If you need this for production, you can leave it at that, though. Making it distinct won't be faster.

#### Explanation

So quick stuff
I did

```
CREATE TABLE follows (
  userA_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
  userB_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (userA_ID, userB_ID)
);
INSERT INTO follows (userA_ID, userB_ID) VALUES
  (123, 456),
  (789, 456),
  (456, 789);
```

and your main query

```
select * 
from follows as left_side 
    inner join follows as right_side on 
        left_side.userA_ID = right_side.userB_ID and 
        left_side.userB_ID = right_side.userA_ID
```

result:

```
 usera_id | userb_id | usera_id | userb_id
----------+----------+----------+----------
      789 |      456 |      456 |      789
      456 |      789 |      789 |      456
(2 rows)
```

well, you could fix it up a bit, but that's ok

Comment: lol I found this approach on my own getting to this point. Good thinking but not the output I need. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement could be translated as per each mutual follower, there will be more than 1 related records in table "Follows".

```
SELECT u.id AS userId, u."name" AS "userName"
FROM   "User" u 
WHERE 1 < (
    SELECT COUNT(1)
    FROM "Follows" f
    WHERE  ((f."userA_ID" = $1 AND u.id = f."userB_ID")
         OR (f."userB_ID" = $1 AND u.id = "userA_ID"))
```

Comment: Easy to read, but doesn't meet the ask of a single query. Thanks for your reply tho!